# Font anti-aliasing not appearing in some computers(win)

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

I have tested my flash game and the fonts are not anti-aliased in all machines (windows). Is there a way to force FLASH to antialiase always?

Comment: Did the non anti-aliased fonts correlate with windows font-smoothing setting? (eg ClearType)

Comment: (I don't have an answer, I'm just looking to help diagnose the problem)

Answer (score 1):

Is the fonts installed on the cumputers in question? Or have you embeded the fonts into the swf-movie?

Otherwise the swf will show a default font and i suppose that it will not show that text anti-aliased.

My first tip is therefore to embed the fonts you are using and then test again on the computers where its not working.

I assume that we are talking of dynamic or imput text here?

Comment: font is VERDANA;   by default in windows